# Code works perfectly in Powershell 5 but not in Powershell 6

Tags: .net, class, powershell-5.0, incompatibility, powershell-6.0

One of my tasks required creating ISO images from the list of files. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/marnix/3944688#file-createiso-demo-ps1) (according to author the code is in the public domain).

My company uses Powershell 6.2.2 only and that's the fact I have to deal with. Problem is that code works perfectly in Powershell 5.1 but it doesn't in Powershell 6.2.2! It gives me following error:

```
    Add-Type : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CompilerParameters'.
At E:\work\MSPV\New_ISOfile.ps1:19 char:11
+     Add-Type -CompilerParameters $cp -TypeDefinition @"
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Add-Type], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Unable to find type [My.FileUtil].
At E:\work\MSPV\New_ISOfile.ps1:52 char:2
+     [My.FileUtil]::WriteIStreamToFile($istream, $fileName)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (My.FileUtil:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

The only thing I found out is that according the MS docs, in Powershell 6.x there's no such parameter as '-CompilerParameters' for Add-Type cmdlet, but there is one in Powershell 5 (5.1 namely). Tried replace it with '-CompilerOptions' but that didn't help. Same error.

Is there any way to make it work on Powershell 6.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually The call is gone in PS 6+, As in the docs `-CompilerParameters` has been replaced with `-CompilerOptions` and it takes string params.

you have to call it directly as the following

```
Add-Type -CompilerOptions "/unsafe" -TypeDefinition
```

If you are coming from `function New-IsoFile` here is the full code

```
function New-IsoFile 
{   
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Source')]Param( 
    [parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true, ParameterSetName='Source')]$Source,  
    [parameter(Position=2)][string]$Path = "$env:temp\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.ffff')).iso",  
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_ -PathType Leaf})][string]$BootFile = $null, 
    [ValidateSet('CDR','CDRW','DVDRAM','DVDPLUSR','DVDPLUSRW','DVDPLUSR_DUALLAYER','DVDDASHR','DVDDASHRW','DVDDASHR_DUALLAYER','DISK','DVDPLUSRW_DUALLAYER','BDR','BDRE')][string] $Media = 'DVDPLUSRW_DUALLAYER', 
    [string]$Title = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.ffff"),  
    [switch]$Force, 
    [parameter(ParameterSetName='Clipboard')][switch]$FromClipboard 
  ) 
  
  Begin {  
    ($cp = new-object System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters).CompilerOptions = '/unsafe' 
    if (!('ISOFile' -as [type])) {  
      Add-Type -CompilerOptions "/unsafe" -TypeDefinition @'
public class ISOFile  
{ 
  public unsafe static void Create(string Path, object Stream, int BlockSize, int TotalBlocks)  
  {  
    int bytes = 0;  
    byte[] buf = new byte[BlockSize];  
    var ptr = (System.IntPtr)(&bytes);  
    var o = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(Path);  
    var i = Stream as System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream;  
   
    if (o != null) { 
      while (TotalBlocks-- > 0) {  
        i.Read(buf, BlockSize, ptr); o.Write(buf, 0, bytes);  
      }  
      o.Flush(); o.Close();  
    } 
  } 
}  
'@  
    } 
   
    if ($BootFile) { 
      if('BDR','BDRE' -contains $Media) { Write-Warning "Bootable image doesn't seem to work with media type $Media" } 
      ($Stream = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Stream -Property @{Type=1}).Open()  # adFileTypeBinary 
      $Stream.LoadFromFile((Get-Item -LiteralPath $BootFile).Fullname) 
      ($Boot = New-Object -ComObject IMAPI2FS.BootOptions).AssignBootImage($Stream) 
    } 
  
    $MediaType = @('UNKNOWN','CDROM','CDR','CDRW','DVDROM','DVDRAM','DVDPLUSR','DVDPLUSRW','DVDPLUSR_DUALLAYER','DVDDASHR','DVDDASHRW','DVDDASHR_DUALLAYER','DISK','DVDPLUSRW_DUALLAYER','HDDVDROM','HDDVDR','HDDVDRAM','BDROM','BDR','BDRE') 
  
    Write-Verbose -Message "Selected media type is $Media with value $($MediaType.IndexOf($Media))"
    ($Image = New-Object -com IMAPI2FS.MsftFileSystemImage -Property @{VolumeName=$Title}).ChooseImageDefaultsForMediaType($MediaType.IndexOf($Media)) 
   
    if (!($Target = New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType File -Force:$Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { Write-Error -Message "Cannot create file $Path. Use -Force parameter to overwrite if the target file already exists."; break } 
  }  
  
  Process { 
    if($FromClipboard) { 
      if($PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major -lt 5) { Write-Error -Message 'The -FromClipboard parameter is only supported on PowerShell v5 or higher'; break } 
      $Source = Get-Clipboard -Format FileDropList 
    } 
  
    foreach($item in $Source) { 
      if($item -isnot [System.IO.FileInfo] -and $item -isnot [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]) { 
        $item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $item
      } 
  
      if($item) { 
        Write-Verbose -Message "Adding item to the target image: $($item.FullName)"
        try { $Image.Root.AddTree($item.FullName, $true) } catch { Write-Error -Message ($_.Exception.Message.Trim() + ' Try a different media type.') } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
  
  End {  
    if ($Boot) { $Image.BootImageOptions=$Boot }  
    $Result = $Image.CreateResultImage()  
    [ISOFile]::Create($Target.FullName,$Result.ImageStream,$Result.BlockSize,$Result.TotalBlocks) 
    Write-Verbose -Message "Target image ($($Target.FullName)) has been created"
    $Target
  } 
}
```